# Remove rogue keyboard shortcut in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard

I recently followed this blog to add a keyboard shortcut to lock the screen:

http://hpmalte.blogspot.ca/2012/01/keyboard-shortcut-to-lock-screen-in-os.html

I assigned the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> keyboard shortcut to this script. I recently discovered the built-in <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>eject</kbd>, which is better.

Now I'm trying to remove the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> shortcut, but it has disappeared from my keyboard shortcuts preferences! The keybinding still works, but it's not listed in keyboard shortcuts, and I do not know how to remove it now.

Does anyone know how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Service should have been saved in `~/Library/Services` (`~` means your home directory), so have a look for the file there. Deleting it should remove the functionality (although it should be showing up in the Services section of Keyboard Shortcuts — check to make sure it's not in a collapsed section).

Comment: I've tried looking there and in the Services folder I have a few other automator workflows but not this one. It seems to have completely disappeared, but the CMD-L keybinding still does that suspension thing. I want to disable it so that, for example, in Chrome, I can keep the Chrome CMD-L binding.

Comment: It's possible it got moved somewhere else (although I don't know why). Open Terminal and run `mdfind -name .service` and see if it turns up anything that looks right.